# Zend2: Redirect with query parameter?

Tags: parameters, zend-framework2

I have this:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute(
   'edit_person', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'person',
        'action'     => 'edit',
        'id'         => 1,
        'bla'        => '1'
    )
);
```

I want to end up with this url:

```
person/1/edit?bla=1
```

In other words, convert:

```
'bla'        => '1'
```

to

```
?bla=1
```

Instead of the standard parameters. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a third paramater to the toRoute function in wich you can define the query part.

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute(
   'edit_person', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'person',
        'action'     => 'edit',
        'id'         => 1,
    ),
    array(
       'query' => array('bla' => '1'),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $this->url ()
    ->fromRoute ('edit_person', [
    'controller' => 'person',
    'action' => 'edit',
    'id' => 1
]) . '?' . http_build_query ([
    'bla' => 1
]);

return $this->redirect ()
    ->toUrl ($url);
```